# Extract bits from a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, byte, bit

How can I extract bits of a file as a string like this: "`10111010110`" with python?

I used `open('file','rb').read()` to read bytes but not bits.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the file for reading in binary mode and read the entire contents you'll get a bytearray which you can then iterate over. Then you can use an f-string to format the data.

For example:

```
with open('foo.bin', 'rb') as data:
    for b in data.read():
        print(f'{b:08b}')
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 10 and upper:

```
format(int.from_bytes(open('file','rb').read()),'b')
```

In python 9 and lower:

```
format(int.from_bytes(open('file','rb').read(),'big'),'b')
```

If byteorder is "big", the most significant byte is at the beginning of the byte array. If byteorder is "little", the most significant byte is at the end of the byte array.

Comment: Welcome on STackOverflow. Can yous explain your code? Why "big"? Why "int"? What append if we doesn't format into b? And the formatting is here to show it, instead of using as real bit in program?

Comment: because it was the same as big so it removed in python 10

Comment: How does this perform? Python does support arbitrary-length ints, but how long does it take to form, e.g. an 8-million-bit integer from 1MB of binary data?

Comment: It can handle files as your RAM can take but about bigger files you may need to read it byte by byte